Pearson correlation of different length arrays
I have found the solution for two different array-length Pearson correlations following [this answer] Numpy/Pandas correlate 2 arrays of different length. I have a question.
a. using [1] instead of [0] gives different results. What is the meaning of [1] and [0] here? With [0], the correlation is the same as the provided answer, but with [1], it is as follows
0        NAN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
5    0.281673
6    0.763265
7    0.719178
def get_correlation(vals):
    return pearsonr(vals, CORR_VALS)[0]




pearsonr() returns the statistic (index 0) and the p-value (index 1). See the documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html
